# Meaning of the word 'orthodox' in sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> "If I can not succeed in an orthodox way, at least I can succeed in a
>   criminal world."

What does the word `orthodox` mean in this case ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's being used as in definition 4 [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/orthodox):

> Adhering to what is commonly accepted, customary, or traditional

Or to paraphrase, "If I can't win playing it straight, I'll win as a criminal"

Answer (score 0):

It means the following:

> If I cannot succeed in a *traditional* way, at least I can succeed in a criminal world.

Aside from the word, the clauses don't agree very well with one another. The first uses *way* while the second uses *world*, which are two different things. But that's just my opinion and other may simply disagree with it.

Comment: I agree with your criticism. The clauses aren't parallel. Maybe I'm a fetishist, but I love parallel construction. I'd change the sentence to read "the {orthodox/traditional} world, ... the criminal world" or "{an orthodox/a traditional} way, ... a criminal way"